# Java Class Loader not loading classes imported in a class

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I am trying to load a class using ClassLoader as follows

```
ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
// urls contains the urls for all the jars
loader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]), loader);
Class<?> main = loader.loadClass("Example");
```

If Example class imports some other class. Will that class be loaded automatically by JVM??
Because It is throwing me an error NoClassDefFoundError that there is another class Example2 which is imported in class Example and cannot be loaded.

I seriously don't know what is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried to first load imported class `Example2` and than `Example`?

Comment: please refer this http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: @ Antoniosss I did not try what you said. The problem here is the whole code I have pasted is an application. I cannot make changes there.

Comment: @swapnil7 I have already went through that blog. It did not help me with respect to my current problem or I did not understand or relate it with my problem.